# ORA-01017 from sqldeveloper but ok from sqlplus

Tags: sles, oracle-database

I've logged into Oracle 19c via sqldeveloper as sys and created a new user

```
-- USER SQL
CREATE USER data_owner IDENTIFIED BY "password!"  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";

-- ROLES
GRANT CONNECT TO data_owner ;
GRANT RESOURCE TO data_owner ;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO data_owner;
```

Then I ssh to the SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 server and `su - oracle` to check the user from sqlplus and I can connect fine as data_owner with above said password.

Why is sqldeveloper returning the following error when I use the same credentials?

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Codice fornitore 1017
```

As a double check, if I connect as sys again via sqldeveloper, I can log in and the sql

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    default_tablespace, 
    profile, 
    authentication_type
FROM
    dba_users
WHERE 
    account_status = 'OPEN';
```

gives me

```
SYS SYSTEM  DEFAULT PASSWORD
SYSTEM  SYSTEM  DEFAULT PASSWORD
DATA_OWNER  USERS   DEFAULT PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dropbox for the role (sorry for the Italian: "Ruolo") next to the connection type.

It has to be set to predefined (not to the default `SYSDBA`).

Screenshot below

[image]

And it does the trick :-)

Notice that if you SSH connect to your SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 and as a normal user (not `su - oracle` otherwise you will become `SYS` when you connect `as sysdba` and the password will be ignored) you run the Oracle 19c `sqlplus` then

```
Enter user-name: data_owner as sysdba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

even if you entered the correct password . Exactly as you have seen from sqldeveloper, that is silently adding the `as sysdba` from the its properties - if the role is wrongly set there - but it doesn't show the role in the login/password pop-up gui.